# How to get data in desired format from csv to new text file

Tags: python, date, formatting

I have data in multiple .csv file in mention below format

datetime         |    symbol  |open  | high  |  low  | close  | volume

20-03-2007 09:15 |NSE:ASTRAL  | 6.18 |  6.82 |  6.00 |  6.32  | 0

21-03-2007 09:15 |NSE:ASTRAL  | 6.30 |  6.45 |  5.86 |  5.93  | 20556975

22-03-2007 09:15 |NSE:ASTRAL  | 6.12 |  6.24 |  5.84 |  5.90  | 7321225

I want to data in to convert all to .txt files in the format given below

20070321;6.30;6.45;5.86;5.93;20556975
20070322;6.12;6.24;5.84;5.90;7321225
20070323;6.00;6.00;5.41;5.57;3335387
20070326;5.52;5.52;5.17;5.21;1992775
20070328;5.31;5.31;4.74;4.82;1007687
20070329;4.80;4.86;4.57;4.66;1453587
20070330;4.86;5.10;4.56;4.97;2301275
20070330;4.86;5.10;4.56;4.97;2301275

Date format in YYYYDDMM format, Delete Symbol Column, Delete Head Row, and column separated by ";"

Comment: Don't use screenshots, You can simply copy and paste data from your files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you pls let us know what you have tried? Where you ran into an issue? Please refer to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- Drop the first row. you can use the read_csv function parameter **header**:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(file_path, header = 1)
```

- change data format. you can read  data format by parameter **infer_datetime_format** .

```
pd.read_csv(file_path,header = 1, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

- drop columns. because you need drop column, I suggest read data from 0 row. when you already read data ,you can drop columns. then drop the first row.

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_path,header = 0, infer_datetime_format=True)
data.drop(columns = ["symbols"])
data2 = data.iloc[1:]
```

- finally, to change the time format.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(file_path,header = 0, infer_datetime_format=True)
data.drop(columns = ["symbols"])
data['datatime'] = data['datatime'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
data2 = data.iloc[1:]
```

so data2 will be your want DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks Alexs joe, Above did not work for me